# WooCommerce. Как вывести метки для конкретных товаров в карточках?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет.
Нужно вывести в карточках в архиве метки товаров для каждого конкретного товара.
В functions.php написал вот такой код:

```
    function woocom_tags_list(){
    $args = array( 'hide_empty' => 0 );
    $terms = get_terms('product_tag', $args );
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        $term_list = '<ul class="my-terms-list">';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $term_list .= '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" title="'. $term->name .'">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';

        }
        $term_list .= '</ul>';
        return $term_list;
    }else{
        return 'Тегов продуктов нет';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'woo_tags', 'woocom_tags_list' );

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'dosc');

function dosc() {
    echo do_shortcode("[woo_tags]");
}
```

Но выводит для каждого товара одни и те же метки. Как это можно решить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $product;


$terms = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
    'include'  => $product->get_tag_ids()
] );
```